# biblatex-apa does not work with BibTeX backend

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texmaker, apa-style

I'm using the newest Version of MikTeX and TeXmaker. I am trying to use `biblatex-apa` with BibTeX, but it simply does not work (and believe me, I read all comments and forums). In TeXmaker, the default option is BibTeX. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{MAIN}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You get the error: `Package biblatex Error: Biber backend is required by style.` because `biblatex-apa` *must* be run with `backend=biber`. You simply can't use `backend=bibtex`. So you need to switch to `backend=biber` and tell TeXmaker to run Biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: I think the APA style has _never_ worked with BibTeX ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MWE produces the error message

> ```
> ! Package biblatex Error: Biber backend is required by style.
> ```

That message is quite clear: `biblatex-apa` requires Biber as its backend because it uses Biber-only features that are not available with `backend=bibtex`.
This requirement was introduced six years ago in version 4.5 (commit [5e70972](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/commit/5e70972efd0869563e58ad57da651b35f575f427)).

So you must switch to

```
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

and tell TeXmaker to run Biber instead of BibTeX for you, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Please note also that the file name in `\addbibresource` must contain the file extension, so it should be

```
\addbibresource{MAIN.bib}
```

instead of `\addbibresource{MAIN}`.

Comment: Thank you! It still does not work... When running BibTex I now get

Comment: Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.1 INFO - Logfile is '_MAlN.blg' INFO - Reading '_MAlN.bcf' INFO - Found 19 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'MAIN' for section 0

ERROR - Cannot find 'MAIN'! INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: _Main is my bibliography...

Comment: @peter When you use `\addbibresource` you must include the file extension, so it should be `\addbibresource{MAIN.bib}`. Note that Biber 2.1 is quite an ancient version by today's standards (the current version is 2.11) - it was released about three and a half years ago.

Comment: It still shows plenty of error messages (even more now). I think this problem is more complex...

Comment: @peter What error messages?

Comment: INFO - This is Biber 2.1 INFO - Logfile is '_MAlN.blg' INFO - Reading '_MAlN.bcf' INFO - Found 19 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'MAIN.bib' for section 0 INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8 INFO - ...

Comment: Looking for bibtex format file 'MAIN.bib' for section 0 INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8 INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'MAIN.bib' WARN - Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file 'C:\Users\ga85hdh\AppData\Local\Temp\kEvOPfTtAq\MAIN.bib_9820.utf8', skipping ...

Comment: @peter The `Invalid or undefined BibTeX entry key in file` message looks like you have a malformed `.bib` entry. You need to find out which entry. Usually a binary search (delete half of the `.bib` file and check if the error persists) is the most effective way to find the culprit.

Comment: Ok thanks but that’s strange because with authoryear it has worked out perfectly before.

Comment: What's actually most surprising is that there is no such path on my computer: C:\Users\ga85dhd\AppData\Local\Temp\SgXUOMzqfm\MAIN.bib_6464.utf8 (my system is in German)

Comment: @moewe: Sorry for overloading you with questions. The problem seems to be here: ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\ga85dhd\AppData\Local\Temp\apMHG6j9yr\MAIN.bib_17116.utf8, line 1551, syntax error: found ",", expected one of: number, name (entry type, key, field, or macro name), end of entry ("}" or ")") or quoted string ({...} or "...") INFO - WARNINGS: 4 INFO - ERRORS: 1. 
But this path doesn't exist on my computer!

Comment: Any further ideas? Thx!

Comment: @moewe for some reason it seems to be working now. However, it would be great to understand the dynamics behind it. I think I have to do some further readings on it. :D

Comment: @peter The path is slightly different in the `.log` because Biber copies your file to process it, the message should refer to line 1551 (or thereabouts, sometimes error in earlier lines only manifest themselves later, so you need to check the lines above and below as well). There are four warnings and one error, all of them should be resolved before you can be sure the file is processed correctly. It is known that Biber can be stricter than BibTeX when it comes to syntax errors. So it is plausible that a malformed file ran with BibTeX but does not run with Biber.

Comment: ... Unfortunately I can't give any more specific advice without seeing the problematic `.bib` file.